# What is the difference between Self Test & Extended Test

Tags: hard-drive

What is the difference between HDD Self Test & Extended Test and Bad sectors Test(Surface Test)?

Answer (score 0):

From Western Digital's [website](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3):

- QUICK TEST - performs SMART drive quick self-test to gather and verify the Data Lifeguard information contained on the drive.
- EXTENDED TEST - performs a Full Media Scan to detect bad sectors. Test may take several hours to complete depending on the size of the drive.

This was really easy to find.  It was literally the first option when searching for "wd self test."

Comment: What Different between Extended Test and Bad Sectors Test

Answer (score 0):

From [SMART wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.#:%7E:text=Short%3A%20runs%20tests%20that%20have,during%20transportation%20of%20the%20device.), you can read :

> Run a test:
> There are three types of self-tests that a device can execute (all are
> safe to user data):
> **Short**: runs tests that have a high probability of detecting device problems,
> **Extended or Long**: the test is the same as the short check but with no time limit and with complete disk surface examination,
> **Conveyance**: identifies if damage incurred during transportation of the device.
> **Selective**: tests a range of LBA (read smartctl(8) § t for more).